# How to add class, using jQuery, to every element except every fourth?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website where I'm going to place elements as tiles by 4 in a row. I'd like to add to each of those elements `margin-left: 13px`, except for every first element in every row. Could anybody please point me to how this can be done using jQuery?

Comment: Please post an example of your HTML. Without it, all answers can only be guesses.

Comment: The title is about the elements 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9,.., while the body is about the elements 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:nth-child()`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selectors. Example:

```
$('div:not(:nth-child(4n))').css('margin-left', '13px');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HsbUv/1/

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
$('element:not(:nth-child(4n))')
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/G84B8/

Answer (score 3):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZVd6Y/

Assuming the wrapper rows have a class of `row` ...

And the given **HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <p class="first">first row</p>
    <p>second row</p>
    <p>third row</p>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <p class="first">first row</p>
    <p>second row</p>
    <p>third row</p>
</div>
```

You would want to use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.row').children("p:not(.first)").addClass("extra-margin");
});
```

With the following **CSS:**

```
.extra-margin{
    margin-left: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var count = 0;
    $('.classname').each(function(){
        count++;
        if(count !== 4){
             $(this).css("margin-left", "13px");
        } else {
            count = 0;
        }
    });
```